Create DTO and DB Models from Abstract base class in NestJS?
I come from python FastAPI world and I want to know if is possibly in NestJS to create an entity abstract base class and do the subjacent DTO, DB models from that base class or something similar, what I want to achieve is a way to write the common models once and just add what is necessary in the subjacent models.
To clarify what I want yo achieve I'll share a small FastAPI example.
from typing import Optional, List
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from sqlmodel import SQLModel, Field

class Example(BaseModel):
    example_property: int = Field(title="Example propert")
    optional_property: Optional[List["str"]] = Field(title="Example optional property")

class ExampleTable(Example, SQLModel, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)

    __tablename__: str = "example"

class ExampleDTO(Example):
    id: int = Field(title="ID")

class CreateExampleDTO(Example):
    pass



This is outside of Nestjs. I suggest you choose an ORM for you. Prisma, Drizzle, Sequelize are popular and easy to use. If you prefer OO, TypeORM, and MikroORM would be good to go. Some of them support official Nestjs integration, but even without official support, it's not that hard to use them in Nestjs.
